# Solve the recurrence $3T(n) = T(n/3)+ \sqrt{\log n}$

Tags: asymptotics, master-theorem

How can you solve the recurrence $$3T(n) = T(n/3)+ \sqrt{\log n}$$ using the master theorem?

I am lost in this question.

Comment: you risk this question being closed due to 1) looking like a homework or test question, 2) showing no attempt to arrive at an answer the apparent dead-end of the failed attempt which leaves you perplexed, 3) not itemizing which terms in the given problem make little or no sense to you, and 4) your low-reputation number.  While you still have time, please correct at least #1 and #2 on this list, otherwise some moderator will close it for these & other good reasons.  Only you can salvage this question prior to it getting closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Comment: @AndreasZUERCHER, if you read the question carefully, it is actually quite funny and educational. Admittedly not intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically, T(n) ≈ sqrt (log (n)) / 2. That's the answer to your question. It's very unlikely that it is the answer to the question you wanted to ask.

I didn't use the master theorem to solve this, but a spreadsheet :-)